# How can I develop a live-streaming app with overlay

Tags: android, bluetooth, video-streaming, overlay, android-bluetooth

I have build an analog device that has a Bluetooth module (HC 05) and I want to develop a android app that can interact this device and at the same time live stream the video with an overlay. The overlay is using input received from device.

I only have some basic programming knowledge as a ee student but do not know anything about mobile app development and video streaming.

What language and software is best for developing this app for me as a beginner?

Comment: I’m sorry to say, this is way beyond what is possible with only some basic programming knowledge. I suggest you focus on one thing first, like setting up a streaming server and trying to broadcast with obs, and playback with videojs.

Comment: I just want to stream on a public platform like youtube/twitch instead of setting up my own streaming server. Is that still too hard to do?

Comment: Here is a small list of things to google: RGB, YUV, 4:2:0 chroma subsampling, image compositing, bitrate, h.264 (nalu, bidirectional frames), FLV, RTMP. You'll need to know them all to send a stream.

Comment: Hey @Jack, can you elaborate a bit on what exactly you're live streaming?  The video is coming from the smartphone's camera?  And then the overlay is some sort of graphic that changes based on some signal from the Bluetooth controller?  Can you show what exactly it is that you want to do?

Comment: Yes, the video is coming from the smartphone's camera. The overlay should be just a textbox (or just text) based on the signal received from the bluetooth controller.